# How to write with Spark to remote Elastic Search node?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, elasticsearch

I have a code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "1.2.3.4")
val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")
sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("spark/docs")
```

but when I run it - it tries to go to Localhost:

```
sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("spark/docs")
19/06/11 11:56:16 ERROR rest.NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
19/06/11 11:56:16 ERROR rest.NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
19/06/11 11:56:16 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 18)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
```

How to set to write to remote ES server?

Answer (score -1):

Pls. see [configuration](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/docs/src/reference/asciidoc/core/configuration.adoc)

`es.nodes.discovery` (default true)
Whether to discover the nodes within the es cluster or only to use the ones given in es.nodes for metadata queries. Note that this setting only applies during start-up; afterwards when reading and writing, es uses the target index shards (and their hosting nodes) unless `es.nodes.client.only` is enabled.

make `es.nodes.discovery` false
example :

```
EsSpark.saveToEs(userTweetRDD, "twitter/test", Map("es.nodes" -> "xx.xx.xx.xxx", "es.cluster.name" -> xxxx-xxxxx"))
```

add

```
"es.nodes.discovery" -> "false"
```

in your case

your example :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._


val conf:SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MYESAPP")
.setMaster("local")// for "local" for local testing if you are using yarn then "yarn"

conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "1.2.3.4")
conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")



val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")
sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("spark/docs")
```

Comment: Tried and still goes to localhost first.. Current code:  ```import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
conf.set("es.nodes", "1.2.3.4")
val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")
sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("spark/docs")```

Comment: Can you please write the full example?

Comment: I am getting: 
```sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("spark/docs")
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 8) / 8]19/06/11 15:38:32 ERROR rest.NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
19/06/11 15:38:32 ERROR rest.NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
```  => It looks like it keeps going to 127.0.0.1 even after whole config sets..

Comment: ```org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
```

Comment: can you try setting   conf.set("spark.es.nodes.wan.only","false") ... basically what it does is  `es.nodes.wan.only (default false)
Whether the connector is used against an Elasticsearch instance in a cloud/restricted environment over the WAN, such as Amazon Web Services. In this mode, the connector disables discovery and only connects through the declared es.nodes during all operations, including reads and writes. Note that in this mode, performance is highly affected.`

Comment: see all properties here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/configuration.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194787/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-joe).

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/791 same network issue here